# Error when using django-admin.py

Tags: python, django, configuration

Please bear with me as I'm new to Python/Django/Unix in general.
 I'm learning how to use different `settings.py` files for local and production environments. The following is from the section on the `--settings` option in [the official Django docs page on `django-admin.py`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/django-admin/),

> --settings Example usage:
>
> django-admin.py syncdb --settings=mysite.settings

My project is structured as following:

```
mysite
L manage.py 
L mysite
   L __init__.py  
   L local.py
   L urls.py
   L production.py 
   L wsgi.py
```

However when I run the following command from the parent `mysite` directory,

> $ django-admin.py runserver --settings=mysite.local

I get the following error:

```
File "/Users/testuser/.virtualenvs/djdev/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 95, in __init__
    raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings 'mysite.local' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named mysite.local
```

From what I gathered on various articles on the web, I think I need to add my project directory path to the `PYTHONPATH` variable in bash profile. Is this the right way to go?

EDIT: changed the slash to dot, but same error persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `--settings` flag takes a dotted Python path, not a relative path on your filesystem.

Meaning `--settings=mysite/local` should actually be `--settings=mysite.local`. If your current working directory is your project root when you run `django-admin`, then you shouldn't have to touch your `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've changed the `/` to `.` but same error persists.

Comment: my current working directory is the project root when I run `django-admin`, but I get the error. when I append the current directory the `PYTHONPATH` variable, the error goes away.

Comment: Ah, could be that ``django-admin`` doesn't set the current path to the path that you're executing from.

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace `/` with `.`

```
$ django-admin.py runserver --settings=mysite.local
```

You can update PYTHONPATH in the `manage.py` too. Inside `if __name__ == "__main__":` add the following.

```
import sys
sys.path.append(additional_path)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've changed the `/` to `.` but same error persists.